# Ошибка 400 (Bad Request) в AJAX запросе

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Проблема в том что при отправке через форму все замечательно, но когда отправляю через AJAX ошибка "400 (Bad Request)".Вернуть должен данные в JSON

в чем может быть проблема ?

**Вот сама форма**

```
<form method="POST" action="http://site.ru">
  <textarea id="text" name="text">
  </textarea>
  <input type="submit" value="ok">
</form>
```

**Вот Ajax запрос**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('a.save').click(function call() { 
    var text = $("#text").val();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'json',
      url: 'http://site.ru/index.php?parametr=56&text='+text,
      success: function(jsondata){
          $('.results').html(jsondata.id);
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка 400 (Bad Request) значит именно то, что говорит ее описание.

Сервер признал ваш запрос невалидным, т.е. посчитал, что вы параметры запроса не соответствуют ожидаемым. Без знания API вызовов, нельзя сказать наверняка, что не так с запросом.

Тут - скорее всего, со стороны сервера, вы ожидаете данные в body, а отправляете в query.

Еще имеет смысл проверить, после правки, следующей ниже, что сервер может принимать body в формате json.

Попробуйте использовать:

```
$('a.save').click(function call() { 
  var text = $("#text").val();
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {text: text}, //это передача body
    url: 'http://site.ru/index.php?parametr=56', //отсюда text вырезать
    success: function(jsondata){
      $('.results').html(jsondata.id);
    }
  });
});
```